# data type exception in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the property in pojo that is of type:

```
private DateTime updateddate;
```

Now I have to set it type to hibernate query also please suggest what will be the type.

```
addScalar("updateddate",Hibernate.DATE)
```

It is throwing this exception.

```
org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor    IllegalArgumentException in class:  setter method of property: updateddate
2013-08-17 16:41:08.252 ERROR   [NDC=]  [Thread-73] org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor    expected type: com.rbsfm.ice.common.date.DateTime, actual value: java.sql.Time
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `DateTime` is your own type, you will either need to:

1. map the property using a custom `UserType` (which is basically a Hibernate adapter for converting SQL types to your own POJO types)
2. change the mapped property to a type that Hibernate understands, like `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`
3. use a combination of the above

Also note that you will need to use `Hibernate.TIMESTAMP` as your scalar type if you need to preserve the "time" portion of the date-time data (**but this assumes you're using one of the standard Java types**).

EDIT: To accomplish #1, implement the [`UserType` interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) (assuming version 3 from your use of `Hibernate.DATE` in OP) and map it to your field via something like the following (assuming XML mapping):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <typedef name="dateTimeUserType" class="your.custom.DateTimeUserType"/>
    <class ...>
        <!-- rest of mapping here -->
        <property name="updateddate" type="dateTimeUserType" column="UpdatedDate"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then you should be able to use the custom type for your scalar as well:

```
query.addScalar("updateddate", Hibernate.custom(your.custom.DateTimeUserType.class));
```

Note that these code snippets change slightly for Hibernate 4.x, but the principle is the same.

Comment: could you please explaun in detaul more about first option if possible with an example or update my post thanks in advance

Comment: more abour hibenate adapter and how it works and the solurion of my prblm

Comment: Hi pls expain a little bit about the hibernate adapter for converting SQL types to your own POJO types

Comment: @RamKumar - please see my edit in the answer for further explanation of Hibernate's `UserType`.

Comment: I already had a UserType as well, but addScalar expects an instance of  Type.  Use 

    query.addScalar("updateddate", new org.hibernate.type.CustomType(new your.custom.DateTimeUserType()));

instead of Hibernate.custom (couldn't find that?)